# Concise notation for single arg anonymous function (avoiding underscore) not working as expected

Tags: scala

After going through some examples on the web I realize that there is a way to write an anonymous function without the underscore when only a single arg.  Also, I'm experimenting with the "span" method on List, which I never knew existed.  Anyway, here is my REPL session:

```
scala> val nums = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
nums: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> nums span (_ != 3)
res0: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 2),List(3, 4, 5))

scala> nums span (3 !=)
res1: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 2),List(3, 4, 5))
```

So far so good.  But when I try to use the "less than" operator:

```
scala> nums span (_ < 3)
res2: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 2),List(3, 4, 5))

scala> nums span (3 <)
res3: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(),List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Why is this behaving differently?

Comment: The `(3 <)` syntax is transformed into a function through _eta expansion_. It isn't a topic much discussed on S.O., that I can recall. You could always search about it, and, if you don't find anything, ask someone to explain.

Comment: @Daniel - thanks, that term was useful for searching, and I found [this link](http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
scala> nums span (_ < 3)
res0: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 2),List(3, 4, 5))

scala> nums span (3 >)
res1: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 2),List(3, 4, 5))
```

`3 <` is a shortcut to `3 < _`, which creates a partially applied function from method call.

Comment: Now I realized my thinking was upside-down for a while.  Accepting this answer, I really needed that explanation on the last line. if you can point me to some reference documentation explaining that particular syntax, that would be great !  Thanks.

Comment: Check out `args.foreach(println)` example at Step 7 of [this tutorial](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/steps.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's behaving correctly:

```
scala> nums span (3 < _)
res4: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(),List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

The predicate is false for the first element of the list, so the first list returned by `span` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```scala
scala> nums span (3 < _) 
res0: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(),List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
// is equivalent to 
scala> (nums takeWhile{3 < _}, nums.dropWhile{3 < _}) 
res1: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(),List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

where 
the predicate is false already for the first element(1) therefore `nums.takeWhile{false}` results in the empty list `List()`

For the second part nothing is dropped because the predicate is false already for the first
element(1) and therefore the `nums.dropWhile{false}` is the whole list `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.