# "Missing parameter type for expanded function" when using _ (underscore)?

Tags: function, scala, syntax, compiler-errors

One problem I continually run into scala is with lambda' expressions. For instance

```
JarBuilder.findContainingJar(clazz).foreach {userJars = userJars + _ }
```

gives me an error like:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => userJars.$plus(x$1))
```

Yet if I do the expansion myself:

```
JarBuilder.findContainingJar(clazz).foreach {x => userJars = userJars + x }
```

It works fine.

Is this a Scala bug? Or am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: `_` does not mean what you think it means there. It is a *special* symbol in that context: *any other simple identifier ought to work fine*. Because of this magic, `Some(4).foreach(_ +: List())` "works fine". To see, compare `Some(4).map(_ + 1)` and `Some(4).map(x => x + 1)`. Hopefully this is a duplicate (and closed as such) or there will be a nice answer that pulls from the SLS :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695270/underscore-in-list-filter (good) , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422016/scala-underscore-minimal-function ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593277/concise-notation-for-single-arg-anonymous-function-avoiding-underscore-not-wor

Comment: (Actually, I wonder if there is *any* context where `_` is *not* magical in a *different way*...)

Comment: Also, might be interesting, eta expansion: `Some(4).map(1 +)`. And "not much more complicated than Java" .... yeah right :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usage of **placeholder syntax for anonymous functions is restricted to expressions**. In your code you are attempting to use the wildcard in an assignment statement which is not the same as an expression.

If you look closely at the error, you can see that the expression on the right hand side of your assignment is what is being expanded into an anonymous function.

Given what you are trying to accomplish however you may want to consider the following

```
userJars = userJars ++ JarBuilder.findContainingJar(clazz)
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Although your ++ solution doesn't work, as "findContainJar" is returning an Option[T] not a List[T]

Comment: An option should be implicitly converted to an Iterable when needed. This seems to work in 2.9.0.1