# Leave off underscore in function literal?

Tags: scala

```
scala> val alist = List(1,2,3,4,5)
alist: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> alist filter { 2.< }
res2: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)

scala> alist filter { 2 < }
res3: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)

scala> alist filter { > 3 }
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but integer literal found.
       alist filter { > 3 }
```

Why would `{ 2.< }` and `{2 <}` work? I think at least I should write `{ 2 < _ }` right?

A method that requires no arguments, you can alternatively leave off the dot and use postﬁx operator notation:

```
scala> val s = "Hello, world!"
s: java.lang.String = Hello, world!
scala> s toLowerCase
res4: java.lang.String = hello, world!
```

But here, `<` method is not those kinds of methods which requires no arguments right?

Can you point me what is this usage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concise notation for single arg anonymous function (avoiding underscore) not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593277/concise-notation-for-single-arg-anonymous-function-avoiding-underscore-not-wor)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The linked question is about different syntax options for functions, this one is turned the other way round, resulting in the given syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is an *Eta Expansion* (6.26.5):

> Eta-expansion converts an expression of method type to an equivalent
>   expression of function type.

In this case, `2 <` is a method type: (one of) the method `<` on `Int`. However, `filter` expects a function type. In such a case, Scala does automatic eta expansion.

Note that, because the type expected by `filter` is known, it can correctly infer what `2 <` method is being called.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that `2` is an object, so if you write `2.<` or `2 <` (which are actually the same in Scala), then you are calling a method `<` on the object `2`.

If you just write `<` or `>` the compiler will look for such a method in the local scope, but won't find one. Similarly, writing `> 3`, the compiler needs a method `>` available, which isn't.

You can also see this behavior in the console directly:

```
scala> 3.<
<console>:8: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method < in class Double of type (x: Char)Boolean
and  method < in class Double of type (x: Short)Boolean
match expected type ?
               3.<
                 ^
```

As you can see, there are several implicts defined, which turn `3` into an object of a class that defines a `<` method. So this works in principal, but cannot stand on its own. It works, however, if you have more type information like in your example.

Contrast this with the following:

```
scala> <(3)
<console>:8: error: not found: value <
              <(3)
              ^
```

Here you can see the compiler looking for a standalone `<` somewhere. Note that the error message says value, but this still means it could be a function, as the value type may be `(Int, Int) => Boolean` or something like that.

Comment: So why you can call a method with no argument like `2.<`  and why this is equivalent to `2 <` ? any where address this usage formally? Why I cannot call my method with empty arguments?

Comment: in this context scala allow you to write `(x: Int) => 2 < x`, `x => 2.<(x)`, `2.<(_)`, `2 < _`, `2.<` or just `2 <`. In all this cases scala will create anonymous __function__ of type `Int => Boolean`, which will invoke __method__ `<` when called.

Comment: @incrop, your link in the other post does answer why the `_` can be omitted, but the `2.<` syntax is inconsistent with the syntax rule. If you can call a method like this, it means it doesn't have any arguments, and it does not produce and side effects, like s.toString, unless I can see this usage is address officially in somewhere.

Comment: The rules that applied here are explained in §6.26.2 (Method Conversions) and §6.26.5 (Eta Expansion) of scala reference.

Answer (score 1):

`2.<` *refers* to the method `<` of object `2`, whereas `2.<(_)` returns a **new function** with one argument. The latter is a shortcut for (is expanded to) `(x: Int) => 2 < x` where the type `Int` was inferred by the scala compiler from the type of the elements of `alist`.

`> 3` in your case does not refer to any method or object of any object. `>` is a legal scala identifier (for a method, function or object), but `3` is not a legal identifier (it begins with a digit). `> a` could be a reference a member `a` of object `>` (`>.a`). But neither of those exist in your example. `_ > 3` however returns a new function with one argument, which you could also write `(x: Int) => x > 3`.

This is in essence the same than Daniel C. Sobral's answer and incrop's comment to Frank's answer, but less formal and with more examples. Hope this helps get an intuition.