# Scala: inverse result while escaping underscore with :::

Tags: scala, collections

When trying to answer this question : [Leave off underscore in function literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426613/leave-off-underscore-in-function-literal) I tried to code an example and I faced a strange behavior.

```
scala> val myList = 1::2::Nil
myList: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> def concat:(List[Int]=> List[Int]) = myList:::
concat: (List[Int]) => List[Int]

scala> concat(3::Nil)
res1: List[Int] = List(3, 1, 2)
```

While I have the good answer when I use `_`or `x=> f(x)` syntaxes.

```
scala> def concat0:(List[Int]=> List[Int]) = x=> myList:::x
concat0: (List[Int]) => List[Int]

scala> def concat1:(List[Int]=> List[Int]) = myList::: _
concat1: (List[Int]) => List[Int]

scala> concat0(3::Nil)
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> concat1(3::Nil)
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Is there a rational explanation why `myList` comes after `3::Nil`in the function `concat`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myList ::: _` translates to `_.:::(myList)`, whereas `myList :::` translates to `myList.:::(_)`.

**tl;dr**

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162924/what-good-are-right-associative-methods-in-scala) goes into more detail about right associative methods.  What's happening here is:

- `def concat0:(List[Int]=> List[Int]) = x=> myList:::x`

  - Scala compiler can infer that x if of type `List[Int]`
  - `List` has a `:::` method
  - Because of the rules of right associativity, this turns into `x.:::(myList)`, which prepends `myList` to `x`.
- def concat:(List[Int]=> List[Int]) = myList:::

  - `myList` if of type `List[Int]`
  - There is no right hand side of `:::`, so there's no right-associativity
  - Instead, compiler infers a . between `myList` and `:::`
  - `myList.:::` is the same as `x => myList.:::(x)`, which prepends `x` to `myList`.